# ODE which can be solved without parametrisation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic, nonlinear

I want to solve the following differential equation, which can be solved without parametrisation

$\qquad y^2y'^2-2xyy'=x^2-2y^2$

I need the solution for my student research project.

When I try to use `DSolve` on the equation in the above form, it fails. However, when I manually simplify it, I get two homogenous differential equations.

$\qquad 1. \quad y'=\frac{x}{y}+\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^2-1 }$

$\qquad 2.  \quad y'=\frac{x}{y}-\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^2-1 }$

I tried solving equations 1. and 2. with `DSolve`. I got the correct solution for the 1st one, but the 2nd failed.

How can I get a solution with `DSolve`, no matter which form of the equation I give it?

Comment: in version 11.3, `DSolve` solve the ODE as is. `ClearAll[y, x];
ode = y[x]^2 (y'[x]^2) - 2 x y[x] y'[x] - x^2 - 2 y[x]^2 == 0;
DSolve[ode, y[x], x]` gives  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7ASwR.png)  you did not say which version of Mathematica you are using. And it is better to also  post the actual Mathematica code you used.

Comment: @Nasser, that should be `+ 2 y[x]^2` across the `=` sign, and while I don't know why, the solution evidently is much harder as I am still waiting for `DSolve` to finish.

Comment: Can you add the pieces of code?

Comment: That's just RUNNING in my 11.2 version

Answer (score 2):

Although `DSolve` is a powerful function, it often needs help to obtain solutions.  Here, begin by moving all terms to the left side of the equation.

```
eq = y[x]^2 y'[x]^2 - 2 x y[x] y'[x] - x^2 + 2 y[x]^2;
```

and make the substitutions, `{y[x]^2 -> x^2 - z[x], y'[x] -> (x - z'[x]/2)/y[x]}`,

```
Expand[eq /. y'[x] -> (x - z'[x]/2)/y[x] /. y[x]^2 -> x^2 - z[x]]
(* -2 z[x] + 1/4 z'[x]^2 *)
```

which `DSolve` can handle.

```
Equal @@@ Flatten@DSolve[% == 0, z[x], x] /. z[x] -> x^2 - y[x]^2
(* {x^2 - y[x]^2 == 1/4 (8 x^2 - 4 Sqrt[2] x C[1] + C[1]^2), 
    x^2 - y[x]^2 == 1/4 (8 x^2 + 4 Sqrt[2] x C[1] + C[1]^2)} *)
```

Solving for `y[x]` then yields the desired answers.

```
Flatten[Solve[#, y[x]] & /@ %]
(* {y[x] -> -Sqrt[-x^2 + Sqrt[2] x C[1] - C[1]^2/4], 
    y[x] -> Sqrt[-x^2 + Sqrt[2] x C[1] - C[1]^2/4], 
    y[x] -> -(1/2) Sqrt[-4 x^2 - 4 Sqrt[2] x C[1] - C[1]^2], 
    y[x] -> 1/2 Sqrt[-4 x^2 - 4 Sqrt[2] x C[1] - C[1]^2]} *)
```

Note that third and fourth answers are the same as the first and second answers, if `C[1]` is replaced by `-C[1]`.  Because a number of transformations were required to reach this point, verifying the answers has merit.

```
Simplify[eq/. y -> Function[x, Sqrt[-x^2 + Sqrt[2] x C[1] - C[1]^2/4]]]
(* 0 *)
Simplify[eq/. y -> Function[x, -Sqrt[-x^2 + Sqrt[2] x C[1] - C[1]^2/4]]]
(* 0 *)
```

**Addendum**

As commented by [user64494](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/7152/user64494), `x` and `-x` also are answers.  They correspond to `z[x] -> 0`, which certainly is another solution to `-2 z[x] + 1/4 z'[x]^2 == 0`.  As described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_solution#Failure_of_uniqueness), these are singular solutions, which `DSolve` sometimes misses.

Comment: Unfortunately, the solutions y[x]=x and y[x]=-x are missed.

Comment: @user64494  You are correct.  I overlooked that `DSolve` never returns `0` as an answer, even if it is.  Thanks,